# jQuery: Get all the element id looping all selected options

Tags: jquery

I have an select options which can be of any numbers by name: prod_search[]
and by id: prod_search0, prod_search1, ...2, ..3 and so

Check the below sample i have...

```
<select name="prod_search[]" id="prod_search0">
    <option value="o1">Option1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="prod_search[]" id="prod_search1">
    <option value="o1">Option1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>

<select name="prod_search[]" id="prod_search2">
    <option value="o1">Option1</option>
    <option value="o2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Now with jquery, I am looping all the above select options by name as...

```
$('select[name="prod_search[]"] option:selected').each(function(index) {       
    prod_search = $(this).val();
    prod_text   = $(this).text();

    //here i need ID of current select in the loop
    //...e.g.: prod_search0 or prod_search1 or ...
});
```

I tried with index which does not show the actual ID but giving the serial numbers.
It fails if an element 'prod_search1' is deleted.

Need a correct way to approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `each()` block is running on the context of the `option` tags, so to get the ID of the parent `select` you just need to go up to the parent:

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the `<option>`s and you want the `id` of the `<select>` element (their parent). So get it with `$(this).parent().attr("id")`.